# whats the parameter todo gets in todo.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

In backbone todo app, there is a function like this:

```
addOne: function(todo){
var view=new app.TodoView({model:todo});
$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);  
}
```

I do not understand that what does 'todo' argument receives in the above function?

This function is called by another function:

```
addAll: function(){
this.$("#todo-list").html('');
app.Todos.each(this.addOne,this); 
 }
```

The first function is passing it as the model to some other view. I guess i am lacking something fundamental here. Please shed some light. Let me know if some more code is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this todo list for reference: http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/todos.js

**Short answer**: the `todo` in `addOne: function(todo){` refers to a single Todo model from the Todos collection.

**Longer answer**:

Lets break this down a bit.

```
  Todos.each(this.addOne, this);
```

Here `Todos` is a `Collection` of `Todo` `Models` . This code is iterating over the collection and each `Todo` model in the collection is passed into the  `addOne` function as `todo`. 
It is also setting the context (or the `this` value) within the `addOne` function to the current `this` (which is referring to the `App`). If they didn't do this, then `this` within the `addOne` function would refer to the current model in the collection (`todo`)

```
// Add a single todo item to the list by creating a view for it, and
// appending its element to the `<ul>`.
addOne: function(todo) {                           // todo refers to a single model in the collection
  var view = new TodoView({model: todo});          // create a new TodoView with the todo model
  this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);   //<- 'this' refers to 'App'. append the newly created view into the DOM, hence displaying it.
},
```

In the `addOne` function we create a new `TodoView` and append it to the DOM to be displayed.

Comment: so when we send "this" as the second argument, it means that we are sending the current model to the addOne function. am i correct?

Comment: Not quite. the `each` function basically says "as my first parameter give me a function. For that function I am going to pass in a model. And I'm going to do this for every model."  the second `this` is unrelated to that. I know its a bit confusing :/

Comment: yes it is. But want my fundamentals to be cleared by someone experienced like you. So: " For that function I am going to pass in a model." Is it done implicitly? if not, what part of this code says that?

Comment: this is the each function that is used:  http://underscorejs.org/#each what is passed into the function is defined here and there are actually 3 arguments (element, index, list) (2 you can ignore for this example)

Comment: So I forgot to mention. Looking at the underscore each function you are probably a bit confused. but basically if you are looking at the docs, in this case `Todos.each(this.addOne, this);` is equivalent to `_.each(Todos, this.addOne, this)`

Comment: one quick question: one of my client wants to access the webapp online as well as offline. so is it a safe approach to store all the data in browser's localstorage (for offline use) and then syncing with some backend db?

Comment: Hey Mrinal, I am unsure, you'll probably have to do some research on how each browser handles it. For example, i think for chrome it treats local storage like cache so if you delete your cache you delete your local storage, and for ipads there is some unexpected behaviors.